# Using git / folder owned by root

Tags: permissions, apache2, git, xampp

I decided to switch to Kubuntu from Windows.

I was setting up XAMPP which installs in `/opt/lampp/`.

Now I want to set up my work environment for a project I'm working on but git doesn't have permission to access root.

When I try to assign a folder (`/opt/lampp/htdocs/project-sbc/`) it says the following:

```
Git: fatal: could not create work tree dir '/opt/lampp/project-sbc':
Permission denied
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple solution is to execute `git clone` command in your `/home` directory, in a location which is owned by you.

e.g. in a sub-folder `dev-projects` in your `/home/username` folder.

If from some reasons, the content of the git repository should be located in `/opt/lampp/project-sbc` then you should execute the `git clone` command as root, using the `sudo` command:

```
sudo git ...... (your git command)
```

Also as mentioned in the comment:

The user can change the owner of the folder from root to himself.

```
sudo chown username /opt/lampp
```

Follow with git command in that folder

```
git clone .....
```

Comment: @user535733 Thanks for the commet!

Comment: chown: changing ownership of ‘...’: Operation not permitted

Comment: @jtlz2 please add the original command you enter before you got the error